# How to stablish a partitions & indexes stategy in Postgres for 100s of milliion rows

Tags: postgresql, database-design, query-performance, query, postgresql-performance

For the purpose of learning, I am playing with Postgress. In particular partitions and indexing.

### The Tables

Let's say I have the following tables on my system:

```
webs
web_id --> BigInt
web_tld --> VarChar 64
```

```
Files (Paritioned with web_id key)
file_id --> BigInt
file_web_id --> Constrain pointing to web_id
file_url --> VarChar 64
file_filetype --> VarChar 32
```

```
html_tags
tag_id --> BigInt
tag_name --> VarChar 64
```

```
html_tag_value (Partitioned with web_id key)
tv_id --> BigIng
tv_value --> Text
```

#### Table Sizes

##### Data writting

- The system adds 24000 new `web_id` per day
  -- For each web, will be 20000 `file_id`.
  -- Writting 86400 new `file_id` per day.
- For each file, will be 100 `html_tag_value.tv_id`
  -- Writting 8640000 new `html_tag_value.tv_id` per day.
- HTML_tags has a fixed size of 100000 rows.

In a week's time, the tables will be:

- 168000 `web_id`
- 604800 `file_id`
- 60480000 `html_tag_value.tv_id`

If this numbers do not fit what I am trying to exemplify, just multiply all of them by 10000

##### Data removal

All tables will have data for the X time. Anything earlier than that is removed to keep a constant size.

### The premises

1. The DB is PG SQL.
2. A system will be writting data at a constant pace.
3. A system will read data at random times with similar queries and different size of results fetched.
4. Each table has an index on its primary key, column ending in `_id`
5. If a column will be used for seach, will have an index as well (`filetypes.file_filetype`)
6. Data reading should go as fast as possible.
7. Data writting does not have a tight time constrain. It can be a bit "slower".

I assume, having better and bigger servers will help, but on this case I would like to understand the use of data partitioning.

### The approach.

I currently have indexes `btree` when the column value is not guarantee to be unique. Otherwise the indexes are `hash`.

[From the pg documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#:%7E:text=All%20rows%20inserted%20into%20a,bounds%20of%20its%20original%20partition.), my understanding is that I can create a new partition every **X** web_id rows, but it leads to inconsistencies on the table sizes. Also, when retrieving data using `JOIN html_tags`, it is significantly slow (say 10s of seconds).

The data stored in `html_tag_value.tv_value`, is currently stored as text, but it contains bools, datetimes and strings that I have casted to text to store. This seems like a horrible approach as I miss many features in terms of efficiency on the search.

### Questions

- How can the data partitions be improved?
  -- Setting a fixed number of rows on `html_tag_value.tv_id`?
- How can I handle the `html_tag_value.tv_values` to make the most out of PG? (i.e: Seach by date range)
- Is it worth to put the data into their respective tables, or have a "reading-table" with all the data put together and synced every so often?

Thanks for reading! :)

-- EDIT --
As for clarity on the questions:

- What is a better partitioning stragy based on "web_id":
  -- Partition it every 100 web_ids, so all the html_tag_values are within the same table always?
  -- Or, partition html_tag_values every 1000000 values so all of them are the same size and I can expect a consistent time on queries, but not all the values from the same web_id are "together"?
- How to store html_tag_values efficiently? Currently are type "text", but in reality they can be "bool", "datetimes", "str", ...
  --- Is it better have a table for each data type?
  --- Or split it into columns where I will only use one per row and the rest will be "null" as the value will be only of one data type?

Comment: it's an interesting topic but "How can X be improved" or "How can I use X in best possible way" are not concrete questions.

Comment: Fair point. I'll update the "questions" section

Comment: Table partitioning is not a performance tuning tool. In your case the only sensible partitioning key is the date/time for "Anything earlier than that is removed".

Comment: In that case, if the system is not performing on a constant pace, it will lead to different sizes... Any comment regarding the data types approach? Latest question on the update.